# unrecognized selector sent to instance while linking static library?

Tags: iphone, ios5, static-libraries, xcode4.3

I am new to this iPhone development.Now i am trying to develop a static library. i was successful in creating the library.But got stuck with a problem when i tried to access a function its showing error 
"unrecognized selector sent to instance " .When i searched most of them was telling to put -objc in other linker flags and forceaall and all load .But nothing worked.

I had referred this site for developing the library.
http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

the common reason that causes the error message is when you are invoking a method which is not declared in interface class (.h) or not existing at all.

```
@interface YourClass
//other programmers forget to declare method in header
-(void)declaredMethod;
@end


@implementation YourClass
 -(void)declaredMethod
   { 
     //this is fine
   }
 -(void)undeclaredMethod
   {
    // declaration in header is missing
    // will throw exception
   }
@end
```

Comment: i have declared that in ma header file then too its showing this error